# Looking for a great single level class dip for bard, no spell progression needed

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization

I am working on a build that starts the first 19 levels this way:

- Bard 9
- Sublime Chord 6
- Fatespinner 4

I'm looking for something to use for level 20. The best I've got right now is Fatespinner 5, but I'd like to read some suggestions on what else might be a good single-level dip for a bard. We do not need spell progression, because we've got max sublime chord. However, progressing the bard's spell level would have some small benefit (two 4th level spells known), so that might be an interesting avenue. The two features I'm looking for are:

- Low Entry Cost
- Strong abilities at level 1 (since I'll only be able to take one level).

Can anyone provide something better than the 5th level of Fatespinner?

- +1 to Fate pool
- Seal Fate

Comment: This is way too broad to have a single, subjective answer. There are hundreds of (prestige) classes in 3.5, and at least dozens of them are valid dipping choices, and some of these have a plethora of good features to choose even at level 1, so much that there is actually a [Dipping Cleric 1 Handbook](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=2773.0).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24437/discussion-on-question-by-joshuad-looking-for-a-great-single-level-class-dip-for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There isn't one

Stormsinger 2 gives you a *perform check* as damage.

Incantatrix 3 gives you free Persisted spells.

Bard 9/Sublime 1/Rainbow Servant 10 gives you the entire Cleric spell list.

There's a bunch - a LOT - of stuff you can do for a Bardbuckler if you're using sublime chord to buff melee fighting.  Crusader gives you Song of the White Raven if you're into bardic music.

But if you're a straight up caster, and you seem to be, literally nothing you could possibly take has anything anywhere near as powerful.  Especially at level freakin' 19.  So, take a level of Bard.  Why?  Because Bards.